# Converting to NAND only

Tags: logic

I've been trying to work this out for days and still can't do it.
I have to convert the top equation to NAND only. I've worked out the second line by using Demorgans theorem however doing this would never convert the equation to NAND only.

---

My working:

$$\overline{ A\oplus(B+C) }\\\overline{\overline A \cdot(B+C)+A\left(\overline{B+C}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are basically dealing with a [XNOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate)/coincidence logic gate, whose expression in terms of [NAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) gates can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate#Alternatives) (see picture to the right), with the observation that the “B” from the image corresponds to your $B+C$, which can be rewritten as $\overline{\bar B\cdot\bar C}$

[image: XNOR (Coincidence) Build with NAND]


In [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) form, each NAND gate of inputs X and Y corresponds to $\overline{X\cdot Y}$, so the image above can be expressed as $\overline{\overline{\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot A}\cdot\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot B'}}\cdot1}$ , where B' is $B+C$. If you are not allowed to use $1$, then the expression becomes $\overline{\overline{\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot A}\cdot\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot B'}}\cdot\overline{\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot A}\cdot\overline{\overline{A\cdot B'}\cdot B'}}}$ .

Comment: Ok this is starting to make sense. But what can the XNOR be written as in boolean algebra form?

Answer (score 1):

You should of course use the identity:

$$X+Y=\overline{\overline{X}\cdot\overline{Y}}$$

And an overly complex NOT gate might also be useful:

$$\overline{X}=\overline{X\cdot X}$$

Comment: I've been in library for 3 days and still don't get what you mean. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @user2437672 First you get rid of all the OR parts of your equation using the first identity I gave you, then you use the second identity to convert NOTs to NANDs, and where your ANDs lack the NOT part you double-negate, and then use the second identity to make one of the NOTs into a NAND.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{\uparrow\}$ is functionally complete. This means that the remaining logical connectives can be expressed in terms of alternative denial. It is easy to verify that $\phi \vee \psi \equiv (\phi \uparrow \phi) \uparrow (\psi \uparrow \psi)$ and $\neg \phi \equiv \phi \uparrow \phi$, from which the remaining connectives can be constructed *via* the usual equivalences.